# How to initialize several UserProviders in Keycloak

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm having big difficulties when trying to make Keycloak to use default JPA provider that is implemented in Keycloak (package: org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaUserProviderFactory)
alongside with my custom UserProvider.

My user provider is implemented like this:

```
public class MyCustomUserProviderFactory extends JpaUserProviderFactory {
  @Override
  public String getId() {
    return "demo";
  }

  @Override
  public UserProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
    EntityManager em = session.getProvider(JpaConnectionProvider.class).getEntityManager();
    return new MyCustomUserProvider(session, em);
  }
}
```

and MyCustomUserProvider

```
public class MyCustomUserProvider extends JpaUserProvider {
  private final KeycloakSession session;

  public MyCustomUserProvider(KeycloakSession session, EntityManager em) {
    super(session, em);
    this.session = session;
  }

}
```

startup.cli

```
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=user:add(default-provider=demo)
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=user/provider=jpa:add(enabled=true)
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=user/provider=demo:add(enabled=true)
```

also in META-INF/service i have

org.keycloak.models.UserProviderFactory

with com.demo.keycloak.providers.user.MyCustomUserProviderFactory

So with this implementation and settings, keycloak is started successfully but when I need to access both demo and jpa UserProvider I only get default provider that is in this case demo.

I access UserProvider with:

```
UserProvider demoProvider = session.getProvider(UserProvider.class, "demo");
```

but if I execute

```
UserProvider jpaProvider = session.getProvider(UserProvider.class, "jpa");
```

I only get null.
If I change the default provider in the startup.cli (default-provider=demo) I would then get the jpa but not the demo provider.

Can somebody explan to me how could I have several UserProvider implementation and how can I access to both of them?

Comment: Are you sure that changes applied to standalone.xml ?

Comment: I don't have standalone.xml, I'm having modules where providers are implemented and that modules are deployed as jar on wildfly. This changes are applied to Keycloak, but it seems you can not have mutiple UserProviders.

Comment: Normally, you can define multiple provider. Seems like your startup-cli provider statement always crushes before it.

Comment: On what do you mean when you say that cli statement crushes? Everything is running fine, Keycloak is working, but when I want to access both of the providers I can only acces the one that is default the other one does not exists and seems to me that it was not instantiated by Keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not answering on my question after quite a long time.

Unfortunately there is no way of having multiple JPAUserProvider at the same time.

The only way to add custom implementation in JpaUserProvider methods is to override them add the additional call and in the configuration itself add the custom version as a default one
`/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=user:add(default-provider=demo)`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).